# Reshape a dataframe from wide to long with different row lengths

Tags: r

Here is a dataframe.

```
     ID  Gene1   Gene2  Gene3    Gene4
2003959 PIK3CA  EPSTI1                  
2003421 AKT1    BTK     GATA3   MAP3K1          
2100019 MAP2K4
2005456 GATA3   RAD50                   
2003141 KDM6A   SF3B1                   
2103689 AKT2    EGFR     MAP2    PHKA2
```

I want to reshapre it from wide to long. Here is an expected output.

```
     ID    Var1
2003959  PIK3CA 
2003959  EPSTI1
2003421    AKT1
2003421     BTK
2003421   GATA3
2003421  MAP3K1
2100019  MAP2K4
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your empty values are NA we could use `pivot_longer`. In case the empty values are empty strings `""`. Then first replace it with `NA` using `na_if` with `across`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#case1 

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -ID
  ) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  select(-name)

# or 

# case 2
df %>% 
  mutate(across(-ID, ~na_if(.,""))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -ID
  ) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  select(-name)
```

```
        ID value 
     <int> <chr> 
 1 2003959 PIK3CA
 2 2003959 EPSTI1
 3 2003421 AKT1  
 4 2003421 BTK   
 5 2003421 GATA3 
 6 2003421 MAP3K1
 7 2100019 MAP2K4
 8 2005456 GATA3 
 9 2005456 RAD50 
10 2003141 KDM6A 
11 2003141 SF3B1 
12 2103689 AKT2  
13 2103689 EGFR  
14 2103689 MAP2  
15 2103689 PHKA2
```